# Raspberry Pi Zero actual price?

Tags: pi-zero

I know it is said to be $5 but when I looked at MCM and Element14, it was listed as $13. What is the actual price before shipping.

Comment: Which country do you want to order from? Also a link would help

Comment: I notice that Adafuit had it on for $5 right away -- or at least when I first checked, at which point they were sold out (except for bundled packages).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They may have up the price because they are out of stock elsewhere, so they make more money. It should retail at £4/$5 ([source](http://swag.raspberrypi.org/collections/magpi/products/the-magpi-issue-40)) *for the board on its own*.

However various packs are available which include a accessories kit (USB and HDMI cables) and/or a microSD card, which will up the price to almost 20.

Links to official suppliers are in the [release blogpost](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/raspberry-pi-zero/) ([example](http://thepihut.com/products/raspberry-pi-zero)).

Answer (score 3):

Strangely even as a UK customer of one of the Official Suppliers, CPC, the consumer arm of Farnell, are only listing a [<del>Raspbery Pi Zero and Cable Bundle</del>](http://cpc.farnell.com/raspberry-pi/raspberrypi-zero/zerocables-bundle/dp/SC13974) <sup>Sorry - Farnell links to "Zero" product died within a few days!</sup> [pi0](/questions/tagged/pi0) - at the time of writing they are "awaiting delivery" - for £10.54 excluding V.A.T {12.648 inclusive} for 1-49 off **and no sign of a bare unit**.  By my approximate calculations the headline $5 figure works out to around £3.33 so the cables are significantly more than the base unit.  In the UK their web-order postage is now only free for orders over £5.00 excluding V.A.T. (was no minimum limit over the Summer) **sigh**

EDIT: A response from CPC:

> The board needs certain adaptors in order to be used, we have made a decision to only sell this with the adaptors.
>
> Our price for the bundle is broadly comparable with that being offered by the Pi Store and other resellers.

IMHO That is a bit *off*, it seems to my, possibly warped view(?): "you can have the product at the quoted price - **but only if you buy these extra bits which we will include as well**".  Fair enough that you will probably *want* those connectors, but by not giving us the choice I feel they have broken some sort of agreement, but that is possibly starting to stray into the realms of controversy...

Comment: Isn't it illegal for them to only sell it packaged with something else?

Comment: I think *illegal* is far too strong to use for this, but certainly I'd entertain *unwelcome* and possibly *not in accordance with the wishes of the Federation* - but then IANAL, I just think that "rain is wet - so who am I to say?"

Answer (score 1):

Microcenter [has the Pi Zero](http://www.microcenter.com/product/457746/Raspberry_Pi_Zero) for the official $5 price, but limited to one per transaction. If you want to buy more than one, it will cost you $10 each. I'm guessing that this is to keep the initial demand manageable.

Of course, this only helps if you live near Microcenter, because they are selling the Pi Zero in-store only.

Comment: @PatrickCook I see on your StackExchange profile that you are in Kansas - there is a Microcenter in the Kansas City/Overland Park area. I don't know where in Kansas you are though.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some real world examples, to give you real world pricing:

Microcenter had a SNAFU and I got one for free: I had preordered, the particular shipment was delayed, and then they gave me the Pi Zero for free.  Though, it turns out that the delay was nonexistent, because I picked it up that day anyways.

The MagPi sells for $15 in the US, and includes a Pi Zero with the magazine.  i got one the other day at Microcenter.  It was the last one they had though.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the magazines Magpi and the raspberry pi zero are out of stock in the official store, so the price may rise for a few days, maybe weeks.
I suggest you to wait, but i think final price will be 5 bucks, with free shipping on ebay